# load htm tag based on browser type

Tags: javascript, html, class, internet-explorer

Below is the contents of my Test.jsp page, I want to check the browser type and use a class of css for my td. In case of IE i want to use 'IEMenu' class, in case of non IE i want to use 'NONIEMenu' class. Is the way i have tried below works? Can i add javascript check in table? Kindly help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

```
    <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <script LANGUAGE=javascript>if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0){alert("IE");</script>
    <td id="picture" class="IEMenu" valign="bottom">HelloIE</td>
    <script LANGUAGE=javascript>}
    else{alert("NON IE");</script>
    <td id="picture" class="NONIEMenu" valign="bottom">HelloNonIE</td>
    <script LANGUAGE=javascript>}</script>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a style for both IEMenu and NONEIEMenu, then you can do this to show your style on IE browser.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or if you want the style to show all browsers except IE.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You can see more at https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: I have created both classes in my test.css and i have included tat in my Test.jsp as well. But, when i try to run Test.jsp. Both IE and non IE <tr> are loading. Can i put js check as how i have done above is allowed or is it incorrect?

Comment: I'm blank, can you create a JSFiddle or something so i can understand you problem better?